# Optimisation of a large query-string in postrges

Tags: postgresql

I have a big postgres query, which form programmatically, like there (Qt-pseudo-code):

```
QStringList dataIds = QStringList();

dataIds << id;
...


QString countQuery =
                QString("select id from features where data_id in (%1)")
                .arg(dataIds.join(','));
```

But **count** of `dataIds` can be over million (!) and postgres fail on bad-alloc exception.

Is there a better solution instead of splitting `dataIds` into small chunks?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alexey. Are you sure this can't be broken down? Is there a specific reason the query has to be so big?

Comment: Sounds quite odd query. Where do you get the million `dataIds` and what are you doing with million results? Could you for example loop through them?

Comment: Put them in a temp table (using copy?) and join on this table

Comment: What is the exact error message?  That doesn't sound like the wording of a PostgreSQL error message.  I suspect it is Qt-pseudo-code which is doing the failing.

Comment: 1 million ids gets from a recursive (in cycle) request  before. Request gets theys from a database and collect programmatically from each result. I admit that I have a not optimized database schema.. but this is an initial data